# Linux - Use PHP Mail to send from SMTP Server

Tags: php, linux, email

Okay, Well basically I have been trouble editing my script to use SMTP Mail server instead of using the php mail heres the code i have been using

```
<?php
if (!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['email'];

//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if (!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" . "@" . "([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+" . "\\.[a-z]{2,}" . "$", $email)) {
    $error .= "Invalid email address entered";
    $errors = 1;
}
if ($errors == 1) 
    echo $error;
else {
    $values = array('name', 'email', 'message');
    $required = array('name', 'email', 'message');

    $your_email = "zookenetwork@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "New Message: " . $_POST['subject'];
    $email_content = "new message:\n";

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $required)) {
            if ($key != 'subject') {
                if (empty($_POST[$value])) {
                    echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS';
                    exit;
                }
            }
            $email_content .= $value . ': ' . $_POST[$value] . "\n";
        }
    }

    if (@mail($your_email, $email_subject, $email_content)) {
        echo 'Message sent!';
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
} ?>
```

Ive already checked around but my PHP Knowledge is awful, so I kinda need my hand held through this

Comment: nitpick: you're STILL using an smtp server... `mail()` doesn't do any delivery itself. it just hands over the email to an smtp server. any other library you use will do the exact same thing, just better than the ultra-crappy `mail()` does. Plus, `ereg` has been deprecated for a LONG time. you should not be using it in any new code.

Comment: Is your question fundamentally different than all of these? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmail%5D+smtp. I'm sure someone somewhere has setup php and smtp and posted it to SO.

Comment: probably so but not with the same way i am using mine to send mail as all codes are usually different, cause my php knowledge sucks i have no idea how to change it into my code

Answer (score 1):

My PHP knowledge is kinda good.

I used [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) in many projects. I can only advise you to do so also.

Sending mails with PHPMailer is pretty straight forward, like this:
(taken from PHPMailer example page)

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

May the source be with you...

Comment: I did already look around and found similar to this but i need it to be in the same format as mine as it actually links to this www.zookenetwork.com/contact like i said my php knowledge is pretty bad so im not to sure how to implement my code to use phpmailer

Comment: What confuses you or where do you have problems in understanding the PHPMailer code in comparison to yours? PHPMailer is an Object, but you just have to copy the code and adapt it to your needs (change email, change server, change error message, delete line with attachment, etc.)